# AdMob ad not working

Tags: iphone, admob

I am trying to implement an AdMob ad in my app. I have done everything, but I just get a blank 48 x 320 view.

Here's what I'm doing:

1). Add all the frameworks and AdMob files

2). Open a view's .xib and add a view (320x48) and an NSObject there. Then put the NSObjects class to AdViewController. Then connect the two outlets (1 to the UIViewController class and another to the 320x48 view).

3). Build & run in Simulator.

My publisher ID is right. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using the Sample App? I learnt from copying that! I also learnt that AdMob made me no money! :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had same problem before... here is what I did.. not perfect.. kind of hack

I copied UIView from the ADMob sample code to use as AdView in my Project... 
and it worked...

Comment: Thanks! I had to do the same :/

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes AdMob could not deliver the ads to your app due to the lack of ads (maybe because of your current country location or because of their service errors). You should handle the failure of receiving ads to hide the banner from your app, otherwise, your app will look so ugly.

Try to re-run your app to see if AdMob does deliver some ads or not.